# how can make this two circular containers selectable?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am new to flutter
and a lot of things I'm ignorant about
my problem is how can i make these two circular containers looks selectable, which is means when click on (eg: Teacher) and press GO!, its functionally work and navigate to another screen but the problem it's doesn't shows that the container is selected!
and the another problem is when the user click on how they are
i want the color of the go button changes from light purple to dark purple !
although i have tried SelectableContainer but it didn't work as i want
this is how i want it !
[this is how i want it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRQzV.png)

and this is how i apply it :
[this is how i apply it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFVfC.png)

and this is my code !!!

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:blackboard/setting/colors.dart';
import 'package:blackboard/view/welcome1.dart';
import 'package:blackboard/setting/tapbar.dart';

class AreYou1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const AreYou1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AreYou1State createState() => _AreYou1State();
}

class _AreYou1State extends State<AreYou1> {
  int select = 0;
  bool _select1 = false;
  bool _select2 = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    select = 0;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //Teacher Button
    final TeacherButton = Material(
       color: Colors.transparent,
      child: Container(
      width: 150,
      height: 150,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: BBColors.circle4,
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.black54.withOpacity(0.3),
            spreadRadius: 5,
            blurRadius: 7,
            offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: MaterialButton(
        minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.3,
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            select = 0;
          });
        },
        child: Image.asset(
          "assets/images/teacher.png",
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      )),
);

//Student Button
final StudentButton = Material(
    color: Colors.transparent,
    child: Container(
        width: 150,
        height: 150,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: BBColors.circle4,
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black54.withOpacity(0.3),
              spreadRadius: 5,
              blurRadius: 7,
              offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
            ),
          ],
        ),
        child: MaterialButton(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
          minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.3,
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              select = 1;
            });
          },
          child: Image.asset(
            "assets/images/student.png",
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        )));
return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: BBColors.bg4,
    body: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        overflow: Overflow.clip,
        children: [
          Positioned(
              right: -160,
              top: -160,
              child: Container(
                width: 400,
                height: 400,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: BBColors.primary3,
                  ),
                ),
              )),
          Positioned(
              right: 20,
              top: 30,
              child: Container(
                width: 150,
                height: 150,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  color: BBColors.circle5,
                ),
              )),
          Positioned(
              left: -160,
              bottom: -160,
              child: Container(
                width: 400,
                height: 400,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: BBColors.primary3,
                  ),
                ),
              )),
          Positioned(
              left: 20,
              bottom: 30,
              child: Container(
                width: 150,
                height: 150,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  color: BBColors.circle5,
                ),
              )),
          Positioned(
              left: 120,
              top: 250,
              child: Text(
                "Are You ? ",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 50,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontFamily: 'Ruda',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              )),
          Positioned(
            top: 350,
            child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
               
                  
                  TeacherButton,
                 
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 40,
                  ),
                 
                 
                  StudentButton,
                 
                ]),
          ),
          Positioned(
              top: 605,
              left: 120,
              child: Card(
                  color: Colors.white24,
                  elevation: 5,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60),
                  ),
                  child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: BBColors.primary5,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(60)),
                      ),
                      child: MaterialButton(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
                        minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2.3,
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (select == 0) {
                            Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => Welcome1()));
                          } else {
                            Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => TapBar()));
                          }
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          "GO !",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 40,
                              color: BBColors.font1,
                              fontFamily: 'Ruda',
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      )))),
        ]));
    }
   }
```

Comment: Hi @Badriya Haddad! First of all try to separate your widgets, too much code for simple screen. How could you indicate selected circle, by size or by color?

Comment: Oh, I see. Just add checking: select == 0 ? selectedBorder : notSelectedBorder and on second circle select == 1 ? selectedBorder : notSelectedBorder. Moreover, you could use one widget with passing isSelected and icon.

Answer (score 0):

You can check below code I create new TeacherButton and StudentButton like you want.

```
bool isSelectTeacher = false;
```

New TeacherButton:

```
final TeacherButton = Material(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: Container(
        width: 150,
        height: 150,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.pink.shade400,
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          border: Border.all(
            width: isSelectTeacher ? 8 : 0,
            color: Colors.purple,
          ),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black54.withOpacity(0.3),
              spreadRadius: 5,
              blurRadius: 7,
              offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
            ),
          ],
        ),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            MaterialButton(
              minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.3,
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  isSelectTeacher = true;
                });
              },
              child: Container(),
            ),
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
              child: Icon(Icons.verified, size: (isSelectTeacher ? 30 : 0)),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

New StudentButton:

```
    final StudentButton = Material(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: Container(
        width: 150,
        height: 150,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.pink.shade400,
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          border: Border.all(
            width: isSelectTeacher ? 0 : 8,
            color: Colors.purple,
          ),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black54.withOpacity(0.3),
              spreadRadius: 5,
              blurRadius: 7,
              offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
            ),
          ],
        ),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            MaterialButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
              minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.3,
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  isSelectTeacher = false;
                });
              },
              child: Container(),
            ),
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
              child: Icon(Icons.verified, size: (isSelectTeacher ? 0 : 30)),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```